# cannot import name 'getFeatureClasses' from 'radiomics'

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to fix this error: ImportError: cannot import name 'getFeatureClasses' from 'radiomics' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/radiomics/**init**.py)
tried installing the  radiomics package and also PyRadiomics. But it didn't resolve my problem.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try to uninstall and reinstalling the package using `pip` or `conda` package managers?